call javascript with await from c++ using Emscripten/embind
a javascript function like this:

async function getData(){
    //do something and return a string
}

my_module.set_js_func(getData);

my c++ emscripten code like this:
//bind c++ function
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
function("setJSFunction", &set_js_func);
//...

emscripten::val func2;

void set_js_func(emscripten::val func)
{
    func2 = func;

    //call function directly here or inside a timer loop
    func2();
}

my question is:
i wanna to call getData ( in c++ ) like this:
await getData();

but i only know call it like this in above example code:
func2();

anyone can help me to give some advice ?
i am using emscripten 1.38.31

https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/asyncify.html

thanks, but 1.38 not support?

you can create a wrapper function in JavaScript that calls the original async function and waits for it to complete using await before invoking the C++ callback:
    async function original_func() {
  await ...
}

function js_wrapper_func(callback) {
  original_func().then(callback); 
}

in your C++ code, instead of calling original_func() directly, you would call js_wrapper_func()

i need "await getData" in my c++ code to keep current thread waits untile getData return.
